# Sharing page on Facebook display 404 not found while the page is responding correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem when I try to share my page http://www.enjoy-immobilier.fr/annonces/achat/maison/saint-lager-69/122129193.htm on Facebook.

When the popup appears, I have a 404 not found error. I have tried other announces with the same problem.

I have tried to debug using the Facebook tools : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.enjoy-immobilier.fr%2Fannonces%2Fachat%2Fmaison%2Fsaint-lager-69%2F122129193.htm

The problem seems to be the error code but I don't understand why. I have "Fetched new scrape information" with no success.

Thanks in advance,
Guillaume.

Comment: _“while the page is responding correctly”_ - in your browser? Irrelevant. You need to go and investigate _why_ your system responds with a 404, when the URL is requested by the Facebook scraper.

Comment: Thank you CBroe. Yes, by my browser. When I use the Facebook scraper, I have a 404 error code.

Comment: So find out, why. Check if you got any plugins running that try to "protect" your site from bots, it's usually something like that ...

Comment: Thank you CBroe but I have nothing like that. What seems weird for me is it works for the english page : en.enjoy-immobilier.fr/annonces/achat/maison/saint-lager-69/122129193.htm but not for french page.